# PHP: Security of Large file uploads (like "post_max_size" setting)?

Tags: php, security, file-upload, configuration, ini

Are there any security and/or performance implications to consider when allowing large file uploads in PHP? For example, these are the PHP ini settings I currently have set.

```
memory_limit = 950M
upload_max_filesize = 950M
post_max_size = 950M
max_execution_time = 0
```

What, if anything, could go wrong with these settings?

Comment: Operational implications, yes; security should be the same for *any* uploaded file, be it big or small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security considerations do not change by changing these settings. However for performance the following is valid:

The art of serving users in a performing way is to offer enough ressources to what is requested by the sum of your users. Translating this into examples upon your settings would be something like:

10 users uploading 950 MB would require you to serve 9.5 GB of bandwidth and I/O throughput (which is eg. ipacted by disk speed) in a performing manner. I as user could probably live with uploading 950 MB in 1 minute, but would be dissatisfied with this taking me an hour.

100 users uploading 950 MB would require you to serve 95 GB...

1000 users uploading 950 MB would reuire you to serve 950 GB...
...

Of cause not all of your users go for max at all the time and even concurrent uploads might be limited. However these Max-settings add to your risk stack. So depending on your usage characteristics and your ressource stuffing these settings could be valid.

However I assume you gave extreme examples and want to learn about implications.

When I google "optimize php memory_limit" I get this:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/207935/benefits-of-setting-php-memory-limit-to-lower-value-for-specific-php-script

Obviously you can do the same with the other settings.

In forums you can find a lot of swear against setting those config-values such high. However having this in environments, where ressource utilization is managed carefully on other access layers (eg. restrict the number of upload-users via in-app permissions) did work out for me in past very well.

Comment: "`10 users uploading 950 MB ... require you to serve 9.5 GB of bandwidth`" **Wrong,** no matter if `php.ini` limit is `1 MB` or `950 MB`, the exact same bandwidth is enough - of course, user needs to wait a little longer if a larger file is uploading.

Comment: "`not all of your users go for max`" **Wrong,** the *Browser* always goes for maximum upload speed; it never limits itself to your `php.ini` settings.

Answer (score 0):

There are some security considerations when changing `post_max_size` setting.

See below example and solution.

**But** unlike said in the other answer(s),
your Server's or Client's bandwidth does NOT need to be increased,
at least not if it is already enough for your targeted user count.

### Example <sup>(for security issue)</sup>

##### Assume given:

- Server's storage capacity is `100 GB`.
- Server's `php.ini` allows `950M`, like OP mentioned.
- Server's PHP script limits each user to have 1 GB free storage.

##### When:

- A single attacker tries uploading 100 files, each with `950 MB` size.
- The first of said files finishes uploading.
- Which ends/ fills allowed 1 GB.

##### Then:

- Because the PHP script runs *ONLY AFTER* the entire file is posted (uploaded).
- The remaining 99 files will each continue being posted (uploaded),
  which probably causes out-of-storage issues for Server.
- Finally, if server did not yet crash due to out-of-storage issues,
  said PHP script runs and checks the 1 GB limit,
  hence deletes newly uploaded files.

### Solution

The default `8M` value of `post_max_size` is more than enough,
actually, maybe lower that to `3M`;

**Because**, the `post_max_size` limit is checked BEFORE upload completes,
and whenever that limit is reached, your PHP script runs instantly,
which allows your script to handle limit error(s).

**Hence**, instead of increasing `post_max_size`, try something like:

- Implement "chunk uploading", using `JavaScript` (or even `WebAssembly`).

  > For anything that takes more than your `post_max_size` limit.
- This allows PHP script to cancel the operation without much overhead.

  > Because each chunk contains only around `8 MB` or `3 MB` of the file.
- Finally, maybe even suspend user's access *AFTER* they retry too many times.

> **Note** that haveing lower `upload_max_filesize` does NOT give same benefits,
> as that limit is checked *only after* an entire file finishes uploading.

**See also:**

- [Laravel-chunk-upload](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload)
- [DropZone-JS](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone)
- [TUS-PHP](https://github.com/ankitpokhrel/tus-php)
  (or it's [Laravel-port](https://github.com/OneOffTech/laravel-tus-upload))